# pidora nodejs is resulting an error

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm getting this below error when trying to use nodes on my PI with fedora variant of OS.
**ERROR: Binary compiled with -mfloat-abi=hard but without -DUSE_EABI_HARDFLOAT**

nodeJS version --> v0.10.25, installed via "yum install nodejs"
nodeJS version --> v0.11.9,  downloaded from "http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.9/" also gives the same error.

any clue on how i can get pass this?

I was able to use the downloaded copy of "node-v0.10.19-linux-arm-pi" with out an error.

Thanks,
-Vikas.

Comment: A lot of things could have gone wrong, my suggestion is to raise an issue with the developers and contributors at https://github.com/joyent/node/issues and contacting them via mailing list https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nodejs

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and I couldn't compile npm at all, so I did what you suggested:

```
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.5/node-v0.10.5-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz

cd /usr/local
sudo tar xzvf ~/node-v0.10.5-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz --strip=1

echo "export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/node" > ~/.bash_aliases
bash

node -v
```

v0.10.5

```
npm -v
```

1.2.18

Hope this would be useful for somebody else ;-)